# mysql INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, heidisql

I want to select one row in a table and insert it into another table like this:

```
INSERT INTO  positionenneu
select *
from positionenneu_0603 where belegnummer like '4106192%'
```

I got an error because of duplicating id values. In both tables is id primary key AUTO_INCREMENT.
How can I do this without id column?
Thank you for the answer.
Have a nice day!

Comment: do you know difference between Insert and Select?

Comment: don't `select *`, then. `select all,the,fields,except,the,ones,you,dont,want ...`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `*` and specify the column list instead, naturally omitting the `id` column:

```
INSERT INTO  positionenneu (foo, bar, baz)
select foo, bar, baz
from positionenneu_0603 where belegnummer like '4106192%'
```

Or you can of course use the `id` column somewhere if you need:

```
INSERT INTO  positionenneu (foo, bar, baz, positionenneu_0603_id)
select foo, bar, baz, id
from positionenneu_0603 where belegnummer like '4106192%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to specify the columns that you are inserting. This also allows you to skip the id field:

```
INSERT INTO  positionenneu (field1,field2,field3)
    select field1_0603, field2_0603, field3_0603
    from positionenneu_0603 where belegnummer like '4106192%'
```